# How to update element at the arraylist on Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I had used arraylist to recycleview like this :

```
product.add(new InfoProduct(R.drawable.cloth, Product_title, "0", Product_data2, lunch));
```

I want to overwrite R.drawable.cloth when I click it , how can I do ?!

Comment: Simply on click of the view change the drwable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`productList.get(0).setDrawableId(R.drawable.new_cloth_id);` Type any position what you want instead of '0'. And then notify adapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I resolve this question by using "set()"

Answer (score 0):

Please make model(get/set) class of InfoProduct and in onClick of item you'll get the position. On that position you can set drawable to different drawable.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I resolve this question by using "set()"